# Como desinstalar pacotes nuget de uma vez, inclusive as dependências

Tags: android, visual-studio, packages, nuget

Há uma forma de desinstalar pacotes nuget de uma única vez, sem ter que ficar procurando ou esperando dar o erro para saber qual é a dependência para desinstalar e depois ir desinstalado um a um.

Se eu selecionar tudo e dar um Del e depois ir na pasta Packages e apagar tudo e depois no Package.config, isso é sinal de dor de cabeça ou não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só usar `–RemoveDependencies`.

```
PM> Uninstall-Package NomeDoPacote –RemoveDependencies
```

> Se eu selecionar tudo e dar um Del e depois ir na pasta Packages e apagar tudo e depois no Package.config, isso é sinal de dor de cabeça ou não?

Não, é justamente isto que o nuget faz. Remover a referência do projeto, apagar a pasta em `packages` e depois remover do arquivo `packages.config`.

Comment: LINQ, faltou um -force, mas vou considerar sua resposta.